# Dynamic form field validation enable/disable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, forms, unobtrusive-validation

What is required to enable/disable the unobtrusive validation on a specific field dynamically in an MVC4 form (based on the value of another field)?

The use case for this is that I have a contact form where only a zip code is required OR a city+state is required, but not all three fields.

So I'm wondering what the process to enable and disable the validation without ever reaching the server. I have the server-side logic down, but I'm having issues getting the client side worked out for whatever reason.

Current attempt...

```
var removeValidation = function(field) {
            var id = (field.attr("id") ? field.attr("id") : field.attr("name"));
            $("form").validate({
                id: {
                    required: false
                }
            });
            field.parent("div").removeClass("has-error");
        };

        var addValidation = function(field) {
            var id = (field.attr("id") ? field.attr("id") : field.attr("name"));
            $("form").validate({
                id: {
                    required: true
                }
            });
        };
```

Comment: You could look at using [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIfEmpty("ZipCode")]` applied to the `City` and `State` properties

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for linking that library!  That looks awesome!  This section of the site is only used by a couple of admins so I ended up just turning off unobtrusive validation and I do the checks on the server side. It's not what I wanted, but this one little piece was not worth spending additional time on given other work that needs to be done!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, I was using the `min` version of Unobtrusive; I changed it to the `unobtrusive.js` and it worked.

In your view add this:

```html
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.steps.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unobtrusive works fine.  I need to turn it on/off dynamically based on values that are entered in other fields.